# how to write conditions in R

Tags: r, if-statement

I want to write a condition in R from :
at first, I wrote this code for generating a random integer between 0 and 4:
`effort <-sample(0:4, 1000,replace= T)`
then I want to generate a conditional format :
#(if effort=0 then return 4500,if effort=1 then return 4300, if effort=2 then return 3700, if effort=3 then return 4700, if effort=4 then return 5300)

## so I wrote these code:

```
bso<- function(effort){
if(effort==0){return(4500)}
if(effort==1){return(4300)}
if(effort==2){return(3700)}
if(effort==3){return(4700)}
if(effort==4){return(5300)}}
```

#but it doesn't work! I don't know how can I fix it!

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by *"it doesn't work"*? What is failing? Give an input/output example **in the question** please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a corrected version of the question's code.

```
bso <- function(effort){
  ifelse(effort == 0, 4500,
         ifelse(effort == 1, 4300,
                ifelse(effort == 2, 3700,
                       ifelse(effort == 3, 4700, 5300)
                )
         )
  )
}
```

But the following version is much faster. It uses input variable `effort` as an index vector.

```
bso2 <- function(effort){
  c(4500, 4300, 3700, 5700, 5300)[effort + 1L]
}
```

---

The performance test is conducted with package `microbenchmark`.

```
library(microbenchmark)

n <- 1e4
X <- sample(0:4, n, TRUE)
mb <- microbenchmark(
  bso = bso(X),
  bso2 = bso2(X)
)
print(mb, order = "median")
#Unit: microseconds
# expr      min        lq      mean    median       uq       max neval cld
# bso2   78.660  119.9295  127.4464  129.7135  139.198   193.971   100  a 
#  bso 1469.328 1892.0490 2781.1861 2115.7405 2156.303 17435.984   100   b
```

Answer (score 1):

It may be also useful with a `case_when`

```
library(dplyr)
bso <- function(effort){
  case_when(effort == 0 ~ 4500,
            effort == 1 ~ 4300,
            effort == 2 ~ 3700,
            effort == 3 ~ 4700, 
            TRUE ~ 5300)
  
}
```